# phpdoc on Netbeans using MAMP not working

Tags: php, netbeans, mamp, phpdoc

I am trying to get phpdoc working on netbeans but I am getting the following error

```
PHP Warning:  require(PhpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/phpdoc.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/phpdoc on line 40
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'PhpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/phpdoc.inc' (include_path='.:') in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/phpdoc on line 40
```

When I run
`pear config-show` in the Terminal I get the following php_dir path

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php
```

I have checked that the php.ini file exits and it does under

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/phpdoc.ini
```

Does anyone know what the problem can be or how to resolve it. I want to use the phpdoc using Netbeans and not have to revert to the Terminal every time I want to update my documentation.

Comment: PHP executable in NetBeans is the same as used in terminal?

Comment: I am not sure. I assume so??? I am using the file /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/phpdoc. Would that be the correct file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit include_path in php.ini to add PEAR's php_dir value to it.  Notice in the error message that your include_path is set to nothing but ".".  As such, the only place PHP is looking for PhpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/phpdoc.inc is right there in your /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin directory.  Once you add /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php to your include_path, then PHP will be able to find the phpdoc.inc file at runtime.

Comment: I have looked at my php.ini file that MAMP runs and it does state the path include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php" so I am a bit confused. I added a file in the /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin directory under phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/phpdoc.inc and when I try to run phpdoc from Netbeans says it can find that file so you are right that it is just searching the bin folder. It is strange as if I run the file from the terminal it can find the phpdoc.inc file correctly. It just seems to be when I run from Netbeans that it fails.

Comment: It sounds like you may have multiple php.ini files, then.  Your error above clearly shows that only "." is in that runtime include_path, so if you see it showing more in your php.ini file, then the IDE execution is not using that php.ini file.  In Eclipse, when you define a given PHP executable, you have an option to specify the php.ini file it should use.  Perhaps Netbeans has a similar option?  A troubleshooting option is to run "php --ini" at command line to see what file it uses, then set up an execution of "php --ini" in Netbeans to see its result.  I bet they show different answers ;-)

Comment: You are exactly right Netbeans is loading a different PHP executable file. Under Preferences > PHP > General, there is an option 'PHP 5 Interpreter' this is the location Netbeans is loading PHP from which was set to /usr/bin/php so I have set it to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/bin/php and it WORKS! Thanks for the help ashnazg.